# Vercel astrojs build error Entry module "@astro-renderers" cannot be external

Tags: javascript, vercel, rollupjs, astrojs

If the vercel hook run the deployment i getting this error.
My git repository is on github.com and i connected the repository with vercel.com.

I restructured my project and now i getting this strange rollup problem. Locally everything is working so here my setup for my project

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.x"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    "prebuild": "yarn prebuild:images",
    "build": "astro build",
    "prebuild:images": "node build.images.js",
    "astro": "astro",
    "lint": "eslint",
    "format": "format"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@astrojs/image": "^0.17.2",
    "@astrojs/preact": "^2.2.1",
    "@astrojs/vercel": "^3.7.5",
    "@fontsource/plus-jakarta-sans": "^5.0.5",
    "astro": "^2.9.7",
    "astro-purgecss": "^2.0.0",
    "astro-robots-txt": "^0.5.0",
    "astro-seo": "^0.7.5",
    "astro-sitemap": "^0.6.0",
    "astro-webmanifest": "^0.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "jimp": "^0.22.10",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "preact": "^10.16.0",
    "sass": "^1.64.2",
    "vercel": "^31.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^3.4.0",
    "webp-converter": "^2.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.42.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.42.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "^0.28.3",
    "eslint": "^8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-turbo": "^0.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-astro": "^0.21.0",
    "playwright": "^1.30.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "vitest": "^0.28.3"
  }
}
```

vercel.json

```json
{
  "framework": "astro",
  "devCommand": "yarn dev",
  "buildCommand": "yarn build",
  "installCommand": "yarn install",
  "ignoreCommand": "exit 1",
  "cleanUrls": true,
  "regions": ["fra1"]
}
```

the error output

```bash
10:27:08 AM [build] Building static entrypoints...
Entry module "@astro-renderers" cannot be external.
 error   Entry module "@astro-renderers" cannot be external.
  File:
    /vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2245:30
  Code:
    2244 |     if (!(base instanceof Error)) {
    > 2245 |         base = Object.assign(new Error(base.message), base);
           |                              ^
      2246 |         Object.defineProperty(base, 'name', { value: 'RollupError' });
      2247 |     }
      2248 |     throw base;
  Stacktrace:
RollupError: Entry module "@astro-renderers" cannot be external.
    at error (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2245:30)
    at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24701:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn build" exited with 1
```

locally its working :/